# Any way to blend two meshes with the same polygons?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I wanted to blend two meshes with the same polygons. For example, a slider that when is 0 it shows the first object and as you move the slider it manipulates its shape towards the shape of the second one. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: hello, it sounds like a work for shape keys, but could you show some drawings of what you mean? Is the slider a completely different object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I do it.

First of all, this is not my method I saw it on a youtube video a while ago

1. You add a shrink wrap modifier to the object to be morphed
2. Apply the modifier as a shape key.
3. Adjust the value slider to morph it

Make sure you have enough geometry in the object to be morphed

Found the original video:

https://youtu.be/SgDhzkv-p6s

do check it out.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted thank you!